# How do you use the Google DataProc Java Client to submit spark jobs using jar files and classes in associated GS bucket?

Tags: java, json, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataproc

I need to trigger Spark Jobs to aggregate data from a JSON file using an API call. I use spring-boot to create the resources. Thus, the steps for the solution is the following:

1. User makes an POST request with a json file as the input
2. The JSON file is stored in google bucket associated with dataproc cluster.
3. A aggregating spark job is triggered from within the REST method with the specified jars, classes and the argument is the json file link.

I want the job to be triggered using Dataproc's Java Client instead of console or command line. How do you do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We're hoping to have a more thorough guide shortly on the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/overview), but to get started, visit the following API overview: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/dataproc/v1

It includes links to the [Dataproc javadocs](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/dataproc/v1/java/latest/); if your server is making calls on behalf of your own project and not on behalf of your end-users' Google projects, then you probably want the [keyfile-based service-account auth explained here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#service_accounts) to create the `Credential` object you use to initialize the `Dataproc` client stub.

As for the dataproc-specific parts, this just means you add the following dependency to your Maven pomfile if using Maven:

```
<project>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-dataproc</artifactId>
      <version>v1-rev4-1.21.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And then you'll have code like:

```
Dataproc dataproc = new Dataproc.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential)
    .setApplicationName("my-webabb/1.0")
    .build();
dataproc.projects().regions().jobs().submit(
    projectId, "global", new SubmitJobRequest()
        .setJob(new Job()
            .setPlacement(new JobPlacement()
                .setClusterName("my-spark-cluster"))
            .setSparkJob(new SparkJob()
                .setMainClass("FooSparkJobMain")
                .setJarFileUris(ImmutableList.of("gs://bucket/path/to/your/spark-job.jar"))
                .setArgs(ImmutableList.of(
                    "arg1", "arg2", "arg3")))))
    .execute();
```

Since different intermediary servers may do low-level retries or your request may throw an IOException where you don't know whether the job-submission succeeded or not, an addition step you may want to take is to generate your own `jobId`; then you know what jobId to poll on to figure out if it got submitted even if your request times out or throws some unknown exception:

```
import java.util.UUID;

...

Dataproc dataproc = new Dataproc.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential)
    .setApplicationName("my-webabb/1.0")
    .build();

String curJobId = "json-agg-job-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
Job jobSnapshot = null;
try {
  jobSnapshot = dataproc.projects().regions().jobs().submit(
      projectId, "global", new SubmitJobRequest()
          .setJob(new Job()
              .setReference(new JobReference()
                   .setJobId(curJobId))
              .setPlacement(new JobPlacement()
                  .setClusterName("my-spark-cluster"))
              .setSparkJob(new SparkJob()
                  .setMainClass("FooSparkJobMain")
                  .setJarFileUris(ImmutableList.of("gs://bucket/path/to/your/spark-job.jar"))
                  .setArgs(ImmutableList.of(
                      "arg1", "arg2", "arg3")))))
      .execute();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
  try {
    jobSnapshot = dataproc.projects().regions().jobs().get(
        projectId, "global", curJobId).execute();
    logger.info(ioe, "Despite exception, job was verified submitted");
  } catch (IOException ioe2) {
    // Handle differently; if it's a GoogleJsonResponseException you can inspect the error
    // code, and if it's a 404, then it means the job didn't get submitted; you can add retry
    // logic in that case.
  }
}

// We can poll on dataproc.projects().regions().jobs().get(...) until the job reports being
// completed or failed now.
```

Comment: When can we expect the official documentation on Dataproc

Comment: if I put the war file containing this code on a vm and use defaultcredentials would the dataproc should work fine, right?

Comment: By defaultcredentials do you mean calling `GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault`? If so, and if you mean a GCE VM, then mostly that's correct, it should work, except you also need to make sure when you create the VM that you give it the `cloud-platform` scope as explained here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/authentication#using

Comment: If I wanted to submit a SparkSqlJob, there is no setMainClass (like in SparkJob(), then, how do we specify the mainclass from the jar that i provide?

Comment: A SparkSqlJob refers to using the `spark-sql` client which is strictly text-based SQL statements. If you have a mainclass you probably mean to run a normal SparkJob, even if your SparkJob uses things like SqlContext inside it.

Comment: can we do the same in python??