# How to submit Google cloud dataproc job from android app

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-dataproc

I need to build an Android app which will be used to trigger Google Cloud DataProc API. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to follow these instructions for [using Google API client libraries for Java in Android](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/setup#android), applying those instructions to [Dataproc's Java client libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/dataproc/v1).

This [other StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35611770/how-do-you-use-the-google-dataproc-java-client-to-submit-spark-jobs-using-jar-fi/35612233#35612233) shows examples of actually using the Java client libraries to interact with Dataproc.