# What is the best way to migrate java hadoop jobs to dataproc

Tags: java, hadoop, google-cloud-platform, mapreduce, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm following [the example from google](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/java/dataproc-wordcount).

In my old code I have the job submit like following:

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
job.setJobName("");
job.setJarByClass(getClass()); // class that contains mapper and reducer
job.setMapSpeculativeExecution(false);
job.setCombinerClass(<JobCombiner>.class);
job.setReducerClass(<JobReducer>.class);
job.setReduceSpeculativeExecution(false);
// some additional configs
job.submit();
```

How can I migrate this job to dataproc?
I try to follow this answer - [How do you use the Google DataProc Java Client to submit spark jobs using jar files and classes in associated GS bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35611770/how-do-you-use-the-google-dataproc-java-client-to-submit-spark-jobs-using-jar-fi)
Instead of SparkJob I use HaoopJob. But the main issue here is we need to submit jar and main class file. Is there any way that we can simply migrate the existing Job class and run the job in dataproc?

Comment: I've never used dataproc or spark/hadoop first handed, but the first thing you have to do is create a dataproc cluster, after that you have many ways of running your job https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/submit-job - regarding your code, I don't know if the job name you specified is ok, also give it a shoot but if it was running in local maybe the configuration needs to be adjusted

Comment: You should start by externalizing the properties to config files. Then you should rewrite mapreduce into at least Spark

Comment: @rajith-delantha how are you currently submitting the job on a Hadoop cluster outside of Dataproc? Generally, if you SSH into the Dataproc master you can run Hadoop commands just like any other Hadoop cluster without changing your job at all. If submitting using Dataproc API or gcloud you can still run pretty much any Hadoop job completely unaltered.

Comment: @DennisHuo Job is running programmatically. I have one linux VM and in this VM, my application and hadoop processes are running. Application triggers the job programmatically with the `job.submit()` and it started to run the job. Now I'm trying to move this to GCP. In GCP I have one VM to run application and dataproc cluster to run the hadoop job. In order to run this in dataproc I think I need to use dataproc java api to submit the job. So it seems that I can't use the job as it is now. I may need to do some additional changes. Correct ?

Comment: You should be able to run it without any changes by copying it into your Dataproc master node in an SSH session and running it however you run it on your current setup. I was asking whether you currently run it with the "hadoop" command or do you just run "java ClassName" or do you run "java -jar myjob.jar"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that code, you should be able to run the mapreduce jar directly.

Hadoop jobs are configured for their cluster from the xml config files that exist on each node, not typically within the code itself