# Invocation on Cloud Function in GCP

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, microservices, google-cloud-dataproc

I want to create a cloud function (HTTP) to submit spark job in `Gcp DataProc` cluster. I created a sample microservice and achieved this by following this link. [How do you use the Google DataProc Java Client to submit spark jobs using jar files and classes in associated GS bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35611770/how-do-you-use-the-google-dataproc-java-client-to-submit-spark-jobs-using-jar-fi). Now I want to implement the same in `gcp` cloud function service method. This is the code in my microservice:

```
public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException {

GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("My credential file location")).createScoped(
            java.util.Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
Dataproc dataproc = new Dataproc.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential)
    .setApplicationName("my-webabb/1.0")
    .build();
String curJobId = "spark-job-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
Job jobSnapshot = null;
jobSnapshot = dataproc.projects().regions().jobs().submit(
                "gcp-project-name", "cluster-region", new SubmitJobRequest()
                    .setJob(new Job()
                        .setReference(new JobReference()
                            .setJobId(curJobId))
                        .setPlacement(new JobPlacement()
                            .setClusterName("cluster-name"))
                        .setSparkJob(new SparkJob()
                            .setMainClass("MainMethod")
                            .setJarFileUris(ImmutableList.of("jarfilelocation"))
                            )))
                .execute();
}
```

While executing this code job gets created in that cluster. It is fine. But my doubt is if I want to do that same step in cloud function what credential do I need to pass?
if I keep both cloud function and cluster in same network it may work without credentials. But is it possible to create a `dataproc` without credential in the below code?

```
Dataproc dataproc = new Dataproc.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential)
    .setApplicationName("my-webabb/1.0")
    .build();
```

Also i tried using

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-dataproc</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is the code

```
public static void main(String a[])
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String myEndpoint = String.format("%s-dataproc.googleapis.com:443", "us-central1");
        // Configure the settings for the job controller client.
        JobControllerSettings jobControllerSettings =
            JobControllerSettings.newBuilder().setEndpoint(myEndpoint).build();

        // Create a job controller client with the configured settings. Using a try-with-resources
        // closes the client,
        // but this can also be done manually with the .close() method.
        try (JobControllerClient jobControllerClient =
                 JobControllerClient.create(jobControllerSettings)) {

            // Configure cluster placement for the job.
            JobPlacement jobPlacement = JobPlacement.newBuilder().setClusterName("myclusterName").build();


            // Configure Spark job settings.
            SparkJob sparkJob =
                SparkJob.newBuilder()
                    .setMainClass("mymain")
                    .addJarFileUris("myJarFile")
                    .build();

            Job job =
                Job.newBuilder().setPlacement(jobPlacement).setSparkJob(sparkJob).build();

            // Submit an asynchronous request to execute the job.
            OperationFuture<Job, JobMetadata> submitJobAsOperationAsyncRequest =
                jobControllerClient.submitJobAsOperationAsync("myProjectId", "us-central1", job);

            Job response = submitJobAsOperationAsyncRequest.get();

            // Print output from Google Cloud Storage.
            Matcher matches =
                Pattern.compile("gs://(.*?)/(.*)").matcher(response.getDriverOutputResourceUri());
            matches.matches();

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // If the job does not complete successfully, print the error message.
            System.err.println(String.format("submitJob: %s ", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
```

In the above dependency i couldn't set jobId. How can i set JobId using this?

Can anyone suggests any possible approaches?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you share your dependencies of your libraries? They seem outdated...

Comment: iam using `<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-dataproc</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev4-1.21.0</version>
        </dependency>` dependency to invoke dataproc

Comment: Why you don't use this one? `        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-dataproc</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>`. The JobClient is easier to use!

Comment: As you said, i tried using this library, and i am able to submit job in the cluster. but unable to set jobId property. My Main objective to move this method to cloud function is to set dynamic jobId. Because if same jobId exists will throws error in dataproc cluster. And i found we can set dynamic jobId only through submit api. i also attached code that i wrote using this library. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you set the job ID when you submit it to the dataproc cluster. You can find that in [the dataproc API](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.jobs/submit). If you have a closer look to the [Job object](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.jobs#Job) to set in parameter.

Here you have a job UUID. And the comment is clear: output only, use reference.job_id to set a job ID

Ok, go to [reference object](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.jobs#JobReference) and you can define a JobID and a project ID.

Now, let's do that with the library: In the job object, add a reference object with project ID and job ID.

```
Job job = Job.newBuilder().setReference(
   JobReference.newBuilder().setJobId("123").setProjectId("myProjectId").build())
  .setPlacement(jobPlacement).setSparkJob(sparkJob).build();
```

Comment: Doc and libraries are close. You need to understand how they work; that's why I shared my path to provide you an example! Note: I never ran a Dataproc job, but I was sure it will work!